# I need to create a simple database for use in an Angular/Node demo. What is the path of least resistance to adding such a database to my demo?

Tags: javascript, database, angularjs, node.js

I need to create a simple database for use in an Angular/Node demo. What is the path of least resistance to adding such a database to my demo?

Incidentally, I cannot use the MEAN stack.

Edit: I failed to mention that I'm running the demo from my local environment--from my laptop.

Comment: Do you have to host this database? If not, there are plenty of 3rd party cloud databases out there (e.g., Firebase).

Comment: Ah, I failed to mention that I'm running this demo entirely from my local environment--my laptop.

Comment: Michael, your local Angular/Node app can API to Firebase. There are documentations on how to do this but it might be a lil overkill. Josh's SQLite answer would be best for a simple local app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path of least resistance would be to use `Sequelize` and `sqlite3` in your application.

Start off by running `npm install sequelize sqlite3`.

Then in your code

```
var Sequelize = require( 'sequelize' )
var connection = Sequelize.connect( undefined, {
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: __dirname + '/db.sqlite'
})
```

Tada, you have a database connection syncing to a local sqlite DB.

You'll likely need to consult the [Sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) to use this connection.

If, however, you wanted an **API** for your angular demo, [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @MichaelP. If this solves your problem, could you please check back and mark this answer as correct? :)

Comment: You've got it. Thanks, again. It was json-server that did the trick.

Comment: I have a question, this exact question, but instead of `Incidentally, I cannot use the MEAN stack.` --> `Incidentally, I completely want to use the MEAN stack.`